# HttpClient exception in Windows service, but not in WinForms and Console application

Tags: async-await, service, dotnet-httpclient

I am experiencing an issue where an async call works in my WinForms and Console test applications, but not when I implement the same code in my intended target format - a Windows service.

I always get the "A task was canceled" exception - and I can't figure out why :|

---

```
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TotalArchiveService.CustomerServices.<ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\DeveloperArea\Dev\src\TotalArchiveService\CustomerServices.cs:line 123
```

---

Using Fiddler, I can see that the Windows service doesn't even call the service. At least there are no traces of it in the Fiddler log.

The following are code examples, where the two first ones are the WinForms and Console variants respectively. The last on is the non functioning Windows service.

In the Windows Service, the ValidateCustomer method is called in the OnElapsedTime method of the Windows service. I have tried several intervals, as I suspected that there were some kind of overlap of calls due to the async here, but it doesn't change anything. Even if it had been, I'd thought that I'd seen some traces of the first call in Fiddler, but there's nothing.

I am using .NET Framework 4.8 for the service and WinForms variants. .NET 6.0 for the Console app.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

### WinForms

```
        private static async Task<string> ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2(string customerNumber)
        {
              REMOVED SECTION WHERE INTERNAL PARAMS WERE UPDATED FROMN CONFIG.

            }
            catch (Exception _ex)
            {
                _status = "CONFIG_ERROR";
            }

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout) })
                {
                    // Create HTTP request.
                    var customerBuilder = new UriBuilder(new Uri($"{_endpoint}"));
                    var customerRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, customerBuilder.Uri);

                    // Set SOAP action
                    customerRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");

                    // SOAP body content
                    string xmlSOAP = GetXmlSOAP("CUSTOMERREAD", _sourceApplication, _destinationApplication, _function, _version, _username, _channel, _orgId, _orgUnit, customerNumber);
                    customerRequest.Content = new StringContent(xmlSOAP, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

                    // Add signature headers to request object
                    await SignHttpRequestMessage(customerRequest);

                    // Call service
                    var customerResponse = await client.SendAsync(customerRequest);

                    //Response handling
                    if (customerResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Do what you want with response body
                        var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        _status = "CUSTOMER_EXISTS";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _status = "CUSTOMER_READ_EXCEPTION";
                        var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var message = $"Response returned with status {customerResponse.StatusCode}. Reason: {customerResponse.ReasonPhrase}";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _ex)
            {
                _status = "SERVICE_ERROR";
            }

            return _status;
        }

        static async Task SignHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // externalize configuration of these
            string certPath = "";
            string keyStorePassword = "";
            string keyId = "";

            certPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\cert2\cert.pfx"); // path to keystorefile
            keyStorePassword = "REMOVED";
            keyId = "REMOVED";

            X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, keyStorePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddHttpMessageSigning()
                .UseKeyId(keyId)
                .UseSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.CreateForSigning(cert, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
                .UseDigestAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)
                .UseUseDeprecatedAlgorithmParameter()
                .UseNonce(false)
                .UseHeaders()
                .Services;
            using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                using (var signerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestSignerFactory>())
                {
                    var requestSigner = signerFactory.CreateFor(keyId);
                    await requestSigner.Sign(request);
                }
            }
            request.Headers.Add("Signature", request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());
            request.Headers.Authorization = null;
        }

        private static string GetXmlSOAP(string method, string sourceApplication, string destinationApplication, string function, string version, string username, string channel, string orgId, string orgUnit, string customerNumber)
        {
            string _xmlSOAP = "";

            if (method.ToUpper() == "CUSTOMERREAD")
            {
                _xmlSOAP = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                          xmlns:wsc=""http://REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn=""urn:REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn1=""urn:REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn2=""urn:REMOVED"">
        <soapenv:Header>
          <wsc:AutHeader>
         <wsc:SourceApplication>" + sourceApplication + @"</wsc:SourceApplication>
         <wsc:DestinationApplication>" + destinationApplication + @"</wsc:DestinationApplication>
         <wsc:Function>" + function + @"</wsc:Function>
         <wsc:Version>" + version + @"</wsc:Version>
         <wsc:ClientContext>
            <wsc:userid>" + username + @"</wsc:userid>
            <wsc:credentials/>
            <wsc:channel>" + channel + @"</wsc:channel>
            <wsc:orgid>" + orgId + @"</wsc:orgid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:orgunit>" + orgUnit + @"</wsc:orgunit>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:customerid>" + customerNumber + @"</wsc:customerid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:locale>no_NO</wsc:locale>
            <wsc:ip>127.0.0.1</wsc:ip>
         </wsc:ClientContext>
      </wsc:AutHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:customerReadRequest>
            <urn:readQualification>
                <urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
                    <urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>" + customerNumber + @"</urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>
                </urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
            </urn:readQualification>
        </urn:customerReadRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
            }

            return _xmlSOAP;
        }

        private void cmdCustomerRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Status:";
            //ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2(tbCustomerNumber.Text.Trim());
            CallValidateCustomerAsync(tbCustomerNumber.Text.Trim());
        }

        private async void CallValidateCustomerAsync(string customerNumber)
        {
            string result = await ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2(customerNumber);
            lblStatus.Text = "Status: " + result;
        }
```

---

### Console

```
static async Task ExampleRequest()
{
    var timeout = 30;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) })
        {
            int textidx = 2;

// URL to soap service
            var endpointUrlCustomer = "https://REMOVED";

            // Create HTTP request.
            var customerBuilder = new UriBuilder(new Uri($"{endpointUrlCustomer}"));
            var customerRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, customerBuilder.Uri);
            // set SOAP action
            customerRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
            // set SOAP body content 
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("************************* CUSTOMER ***********************");
            string xmlSOAP = GetXmlSOAP("CUSTOMER", textidx);
            customerRequest.Content = new StringContent(xmlSOAP, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            // Add signature headers to request object
            await SignHttpRequestMessage(customerRequest, textidx);
            Console.WriteLine("Signed request HTTP");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(customerRequest + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Signed request XML");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(customerRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + Environment.NewLine);

            // Perform request
            Console.WriteLine("Send request");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------"); 
            var customerResponse = await client.SendAsync(customerRequest);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Response HTTP");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(customerResponse + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Response result XML");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + Environment.NewLine);
            if (customerResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Do what you want with response body
                var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var message = $"Response returned with status {customerResponse.StatusCode}. Reason: {customerResponse.ReasonPhrase}";
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
static async Task SignHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, int testIdx)
{
    // externalize configuration of these
    string certPath = "";
    string keyStorePassword = "";
    string keyId = "";

    if (testIdx == 1)
    {
        keyStorePassword = "REMOVED";
        keyId = "REMOVED";
    }
    if (testIdx == 2)
    {
        certPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\cert2\cert.pfx"); // path to keystorefile
        keyStorePassword = "REMOVED";
        keyId = "REMOVED";
    }
    else if (testIdx == 3)
    {
        certPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"REMOVED"); // path to keystorefile
        keyStorePassword = "REMOVED";
        keyId = "REMOVED";
    }

    X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, keyStorePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddHttpMessageSigning()
        .UseKeyId(keyId)
        .UseSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.CreateForSigning(cert, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
        .UseDigestAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)
        .UseUseDeprecatedAlgorithmParameter()
        .UseNonce(false)
        .UseHeaders()
        .Services;
    using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
    {
        using (var signerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestSignerFactory>())
        {
            var requestSigner = signerFactory.CreateFor(keyId);
            await requestSigner.Sign(request);
        }
    }
    request.Headers.Add("Signature", request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());
    request.Headers.Authorization = null;
}

static string GetXmlSOAP(string operation, int testIdx)
{
    string xmlSOAP = "";

    if (operation == "CUSTOMER")
    {
        if (testIdx == 1)
        {
           REMOVED
        }

        if (testIdx == 2)
        {
            xmlSOAP = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                          xmlns:wsc=""http://REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn=""urn:REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn1=""urn:REMOVED"" 
                          xmlns:urn2=""urn:REMOVED"">
        <soapenv:Header>
      <wsc:AutHeader>
         <wsc:SourceApplication>REMOVED</wsc:SourceApplication>
         <wsc:DestinationApplication>REMOVED</wsc:DestinationApplication>
         <wsc:Function>REMOVED</wsc:Function>
         <wsc:Version>REMOVED</wsc:Version>
         <wsc:ClientContext>
            <wsc:userid>REMOVED</wsc:userid>
            <wsc:credentials/>
            <wsc:channel>REMOVED</wsc:channel>
            <wsc:orgid>REMOVED</wsc:orgid>
            <wsc:orgunit>REMOVED</wsc:orgunit>
            <wsc:customerid>REMOVED</wsc:customerid>
            <wsc:locale>no_NO</wsc:locale>
            <wsc:ip>127.0.0.1</wsc:ip>
         </wsc:ClientContext>
      </wsc:AutHeader>
       </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <urn:customerReadRequest>
                <urn:readQualification>
                    <urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
                        <urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>REMOVED</urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>
                    </urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
                </urn:readQualification>
            </urn:customerReadRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
        }

        if (testIdx == 3)
        {
           REMOVED
        }
    }
}
```

### Windows service

```
    internal class CustomerServices
    {
        private static bool _extendedLogging = true;

        public static string ValidateCustomer(string customerNumber)
        {
            string _status = "";
            string _servicesType = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("ServicesType");

            //TODO: Check format, ref. "UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT" in HandleValidateCustomerException
            //TODO: Check existing, ref. "CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND" in HandleValidateCustomerException

            if (_servicesType == "COREWSGEN2")
            {
                _status = ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2(customerNumber).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            return _status;
        }

        private static async Task<string> ValidateCustomerCoreWSGen2(string customerNumber)
        {
            string _status = "";
            string _username = "";
            string _orgId = "";
            string _orgUnit = "";
            string _channel = "";
            string _sourceApplication = "";
            string _destinationApplication = "";
            string _function = "";
            string _version = "";
            int _timeout = 30;

            string _endpoint = "";

            string _values = "";

            try
            {
                _extendedLogging = (CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("ExtendedLogging").ToUpper() == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                _values += "ExtendedLogging" + Environment.NewLine;
                _username = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("Username");
                _values += "Username" + Environment.NewLine;
                _orgId = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("OrgId");
                _values += "OrgId" + Environment.NewLine;
                _orgUnit = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("OrgUnit");
                _values += "OrgUnit" + Environment.NewLine;
                _channel = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2Channel");
                _values += "CoreWSGen2Channel" + Environment.NewLine;
                _sourceApplication = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2SourceApplication");
                _values += "CoreWSGen2SourceApplication" + Environment.NewLine;
                _destinationApplication = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2DestinationApplication");
                _values += "CoreWSGen2DestinationApplication" + Environment.NewLine;
                _function = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2Function");
                _values += "CoreWSGen2Function" + Environment.NewLine;
                _version = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2Version");
                _values += "CoreWSGen2Version" + Environment.NewLine;
                _timeout = Int32.Parse(CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CoreWSGen2TimeoutSeconds"));
                _values += "CoreWSGen2Version" + Environment.NewLine;

                _endpoint = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("CustomerServicesEndpointAddress");

                if (_extendedLogging)
                {
                    Logging.LogAction("Application settings used for customer read:" + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "-------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Username = " + _username + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "OrgId = " + _orgId + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "OrgUnit = " + _orgUnit + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Channel = " + _channel + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "SourceApplication = " + _sourceApplication + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "DestinationApplication = " + _destinationApplication + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Function = " + _function + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Version = " + _version + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Timeout (seconds) = " + _timeout + Environment.NewLine
                                   + Environment.NewLine
                                   + "Endpoint = " + _endpoint + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _ex)
            {
                _status = "CONFIG_ERROR";
                Logging.LogException(new Exception("CustomerServices - Error when reading configuration file. Successfully read values: " + Environment.NewLine + _values + Environment.NewLine, _ex.InnerException));
            }

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout) })
                {
                    // Create HTTP request.
                    var customerBuilder = new UriBuilder(new Uri($"{_endpoint}"));
                    var customerRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, customerBuilder.Uri);

                    // Set SOAP action
                    customerRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");

                    // SOAP body content
                    string xmlSOAP = GetXmlSOAP("CUSTOMERREAD", _sourceApplication, _destinationApplication, _function, _version, _username, _channel, _orgId, _orgUnit, customerNumber);
                    customerRequest.Content = new StringContent(xmlSOAP, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

                    // Add signature headers to request object
                    await SignHttpRequestMessage(customerRequest);

                    // Call service
                    var customerResponse = await client.SendAsync(customerRequest);

                    if (_extendedLogging)
                    {
                        Logging.LogAction("Response header:" + Environment.NewLine + customerResponse + Environment.NewLine);
                        Logging.LogAction("Response content:" + Environment.NewLine + customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    //Response handling
                    if (customerResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Do what you want with response body
                        var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        // Log response content if extended logging
                        if (_extendedLogging)
                        {
                            Logging.LogAction(responseBody);
                        }

                        _status = "CUSTOMER_EXISTS";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _status = "CUSTOMER_READ_EXCEPTION";
                        var responseBody = await customerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var message = $"Response returned with status {customerResponse.StatusCode}. Reason: {customerResponse.ReasonPhrase}";
                        Logging.LogException(new Exception(message));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _ex)
            {
                _status = "SERVICE_ERROR";
                Logging.LogException(_ex);
            }

            return _status;
        }

        static async Task SignHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // externalize configuration of these
            string certPath = "";
            string keyStorePassword = "";
            string keyId = "";

            certPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\cert2\cert.pfx"); // path to keystorefile
            keyStorePassword = "internal-sls-test";
            keyId = "73ae28ed2f31";

            X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, keyStorePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddHttpMessageSigning()
                .UseKeyId(keyId)
                .UseSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.CreateForSigning(cert, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
                .UseDigestAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)
                .UseUseDeprecatedAlgorithmParameter()
                .UseNonce(false)
                .UseHeaders()
                .Services;
            using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                using (var signerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestSignerFactory>())
                {
                    var requestSigner = signerFactory.CreateFor(keyId);
                    await requestSigner.Sign(request);
                }
            }
            request.Headers.Add("Signature", request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());
            request.Headers.Authorization = null;

            if (_extendedLogging)
            {
                Logging.LogAction("Signed request header:" + Environment.NewLine + request + Environment.NewLine);
                Logging.LogAction("Signed request content:" + Environment.NewLine + request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        private static string GetXmlSOAP(string method, string sourceApplication, string destinationApplication, string function, string version, string username, string channel, string orgId, string orgUnit, string customerNumber)
        {
            string _xmlSOAP = "";

            if (method.ToUpper() == "CUSTOMERREAD")
            {
                _xmlSOAP = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                          xmlns:wsc=""http://edb.com/ws/WSCommon_v22"" 
                          xmlns:urn=""urn:srv.cus.corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:ws:customer:v20_1"" 
                          xmlns:urn1=""urn:srv.cus.corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:domain:customer:v20_1"" 
                          xmlns:urn2=""urn:corews.enterprise.fs.evry.com:domain:common:v8"">
        <soapenv:Header>
          <wsc:AutHeader>
         <wsc:SourceApplication>" + sourceApplication + @"</wsc:SourceApplication>
         <wsc:DestinationApplication>" + destinationApplication + @"</wsc:DestinationApplication>
         <wsc:Function>" + function + @"</wsc:Function>
         <wsc:Version>" + version + @"</wsc:Version>
         <wsc:ClientContext>
            <wsc:userid>" + username + @"</wsc:userid>
            <wsc:credentials/>
            <wsc:channel>" + channel + @"</wsc:channel>
            <wsc:orgid>" + orgId + @"</wsc:orgid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:orgunit>" + orgUnit + @"</wsc:orgunit>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:customerid>" + customerNumber + @"</wsc:customerid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wsc:locale>no_NO</wsc:locale>
            <wsc:ip>127.0.0.1</wsc:ip>
         </wsc:ClientContext>
      </wsc:AutHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:customerReadRequest>
            <urn:readQualification>
                <urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
                    <urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>" + customerNumber + @"</urn2:internationalCustomerNumber>
                </urn1:internationalCustomerKey>
            </urn:readQualification>
        </urn:customerReadRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
            }

            return _xmlSOAP;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. Everything is tested on the same machine.

Comment: How is it called? Are you using a .net worker or servicebase?

Comment: It is called in the OnElapsedTime event of the Windows Service.


The Windows service is inheriting ServiceBase, i.e.


   public partial class TotalArchiveService : ServiceBase
    {
        readonly Timer _timer = new Timer { Interval = 10000 };
        string _filesCheckInterval = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("FilesCheckInterval");
        string _appSettingOrgId = CommonMethods.GetAppSetting("OrgId");
.
.
.

Comment: Is that (using ServiceBase) a problem - or?

Comment: For some reason, I am now getting an Unable to connect to the remote server exception, with exactly the same code, URI, request etc. as works in the WinForms application. No traces of a tried call in Fiddler. What is the issue with these async calls in ServiceBase :(